# Different datasources in TEST and DEVELOPMENT environment

Tags: database, testing, grails

I'm working with a legacy code that uses datasources. I define it in the `config.groovy` file, but when I run the code en TEST mode I need to define the datasource in a different way:

```
environments {
    development {
    grails.naming.entries = [
        "jdbc/AS400DS": [
               ...
        ]
    ]
    }
    test {
    grails.naming.entries = [
        "java:comp/env/jdbc/AS400DS": [
               ...
        ]
    ]
    }
}
```

Is this correct and normal? Or am I missing something important? It works, but I don't understand why I have to define the jndi name in a different way.

Comment: Sorry, do you write in config.groovy `environments { test { ... }}` or just `test {}` on top level? Is it what you're asking about? For me, `environments {  development{...}  test { ... }}`works.

Comment: Hi Victor, I rewrited the question in order to clarify that issue. Sorry, it was my fault not to put it in the right way.

Answer (score 1):

Generally the data source connections should be defined in grails-app/conf/DataSource.groovy.  You can still maintain multiple environment declarations and the syntax is much simpler.  You can also define global settings for your JNDI connections and hibernate caching.

```
dataSource {
    pooled = false
}

hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache=true
    cache.use_query_cache=true
    cache.provider_class='org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider'
}

// environment specific settings
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "validate" // one of 'create', 'create-drop','update'
            jndiName = "java:comp/env/jdbc/databaseName"
        }
    }
    test {
        dataSource {
            driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            username = "username"
            password = "password"
            dbCreate = "validate" // one of 'create', 'create-drop','update'
            url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/databaseName"
    }
}
```